# OS X - Bridge WiFi and Ethernet

Tags: macos, networking

Simple question, but thus far my searches have been unable to yield a suitable answer:

Can I bridge my WiFi and Ethernet adapters, such that the device connected on the Ethernet port is visible to the network the WiFi adapter's on - i.e., traffic is passed through to/from the Ethernet port?

**Note this is *not* 'Internet Sharing'.**

Answer (score 1):

802.11 doesn't permit multiple MAC addresses to come from a single endpoint. To do bridging, you have to use something like [WDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system). I'm not sure if a Mac has the ability to serve as a WDS peer and your AP/router has to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your definition of "bridge." A lot of times people say "bridge" when what they really are talking about is an [OSI Model Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) 3 router.  In any case this article should get you pointed in the right direction:  [Xbridge: Network bridging in OS X](https://web.archive.org/web/20130831173850/http://www.glassechidna.com.au/2009/projects/mac-os-x/xbridge/xbridge-network-bridging-in-os-x/)

Comment: I've stumbled upon this previously - sadly there doesn't seem to be any manner of download link.

Answer (score 0):

On MAC there is a sharing option in system settings ...

https://whitehatty.com/2012/06/03/macosx-make-your-mac-a-wireless-network-bridge/

Steps are

- Connect your mac to your wireless network
- Connect Switch / Router / Wireless Access Point to Mac Ethernet port
- Go to System Preferences -> Sharing /
  Check Internet Sharing /
  Share your connection from: Wi-Fi /
  To computers using: Ethernet and Bluetooth PAN /
  Let DHCP enabled

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.